# How to keep a running total of Bootstrap Multi-select selected item's value?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have a multi-select drop-down list and a text box. The user can select or deselect any element from the list. I want to add all the selected items from the list and show the total value in the text box and when an item is deselected from the list the value should be subtracted from the list. However, I don't know how I should subtract the value from `totalPrice` when a user deselects an item.

```
<input id="txtPrice" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />

<select id="DDLSkills" multiple name="selValue" class="selectpicker form-control" data-max-options="2">
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

At the moment I am able to add all the values and show it in the textbox. But when I have two items selected and when I deselect one item the `totalPrice` value still goes up.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var totalPrice = 0;
        $('#DDLSkills').change(function () {

            var value = $(this).val();

            if ($(this).val() == null) {
                totalPrice = 0;
                document.getElementById('txtPrice').value = 0;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    if (jQuery.inArray(value[i], value) != -1) {
                        totalPrice += parseInt(value[i]);
                        document.getElementById('txtPrice').value = totalPrice;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is how I think the problem should be approached:

Instead of trying to subtract the value of a deselected item from the `totalValue`, we could instead keep a running track of the `totalValue` of all the selected items.

**Solution in code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#DDLSkills').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    // We're initializing totalPrice here to keep a running sum
    var totalPrice = 0; 
    
    if ($(this).val() == null) {
      document.getElementById('txtPrice').value = 0;
    }

    if (value != null) {
      
      // We sum up all the values of items currently selected
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(value[i], value) != -1) {
          totalPrice += parseInt(value[i]);
        }
      }
      
      // And print this sum to the screen on-the-fly!
      document.getElementById('txtPrice').value = totalPrice;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input id="txtPrice" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />

<select id="DDLSkills" multiple name="selValue" class="selectpicker form-control" data-max-options="2">
  <option value="10">Ten</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

---

**Explanation**

**The reason the total value still keeps going up** in the original code, is you have an on "change" event handler attached to `#DDLSkills`. So everytime you select an item, it'll trigger this on "change" event and run the callback function which simply keeps adding to `totalValue`.

In this answer's solution, notice that I put the `totalValue` initialization statement into the on "change" function. This is so that every time the user selects/deselects an item, **only** the running total value of the list of items selected will be shown.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the correct way of thinking of this problem.